# Python extract whitespace-separated words that may include specific punctuation symbols

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have some task with text and I need to split string into words properly.
For my task I am using **Python3**.

That way doesn't appropriate for me:

```
re.sub("[^\w]", " ", hotelName.lower()).split()
```

because words in sentences like this:

```
"[{(St.Augst bridge), South-West]} . a - a Torreluca! B&B O'Dell! & Cabin& Wastlgasse MM-505?."
```

are spitted in the list:

```
 ['st', 'augst', 'bridge', 'south', 'west', 'torreluca', 'b', 'b', 'o',
 'dell', 'cabin', 'wastlgasse', 'mm', '505']
```

but I need to split terms in that way (to save entire terms):

```
 ["st.augst", "bridge", "South-West", "Torreluca", "B&B", "O'Dell", 
"Cabin", "Wastlgasse", "MM-505"]
```

**It means that I need split text by:**

- **spaces**,
- **",", "!", "?"**
- **"."** if dot in the end of the word before space or in the end of string (to prevent St.Augst => "st", "august")
- delete **"[", "{", "("** etc...

I will really appreciate if somebody who familiar with regexp will help me with that task. It seems to be quite common task to get terms from document.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to do it by hand with regex ?
Otherwise, it might be a bit of heavy artillery use but take a look at an nltk, they have tokenizers that could do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for patterns of non-whitespace between word boundaries `\b`:

```
import re

hotel_name = "(St.Augst bridge), South-West Torreluca! B&B O'Dell Cabin Wastlgasse MM-505?"

REGEX = r"\b\S+\b"
finder = re.compile(REGEX)

matches = re.findall(finder, hotel_name)
print(matches)
```

Output:

```
['St.Augst', 'bridge', 'South-West', 'Torreluca', 'B&B', "O'Dell", 'Cabin', 'Wastlgasse', 'MM-505']
```

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the string in question slightly, and your method isn't going to work. Anyway thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Can you elaborate? When I run my code with the new string, I get `['St.Augst', 'bridge', 'South-West', 'a', 'a', 'Torreluca', 'B&B', "O'Dell", 'Cabin', 'Wastlgasse', 'MM-505']`, which seems more correct than what I get when I run the chosen answer: `['[', 'St.Augst', 'bridge', 'South-West]', 'a', '-', 'a', 'Torreluca', 'B&B', "O'Dell", 'Cabin', 'Wastlgasse', 'MM-505.']`

Comment: One minute, I try to comprehend how your regexp actually working.

Comment: Yes, your way is quite good, and easier to write down. I'm sorry about appeared misconception about efficiency of your approach, it's happened by chance. I think your answer the best.

Comment: no need to apologize. I am glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 1):

**Anwser updated to work with python3**

Well there may be a better way, but what following works:

```
import re
string = "(St.Augst bridge), South-West Torreluca! B&B O'Dell Cabin Wastlgasse MM-505?"
wordlist = re.split(r'[()!?,]|\.?\s+', string)
wordlist = list(filter(lambda a: a != '', wordlist))
print(wordlist)
```

Output:

```
['St.Augst', 'bridge', 'South-West', 'Torreluca', 'B&B', "O'Dell", 'Cabin', 'Wastlgasse', 'MM-505']
```

Regex pattern `[()!?,]|\.?\s+` can be read like "*all characters '(', ')', '!', '?' or ',' OR a whitespace which can be preceded by a dot*"

Because sometimes we are splitting parts of strings that exactly matches with ',' by example, `re.split` will returns list containing empties strings, that why I filter output list at line 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot!) Your answer fit to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, translate out the stuff you don't want, then split.

```
In [26]: test = "(St.Augst bridge), South-West Torreluca! B&B O'Dell Cabin Wastlgasse MM-505?"

In [27]: test.translate({ord(j): None for j in ',?!()'}).split()
Out[27]: 
['St.Augst',
 'bridge',
 'South-West',
 'Torreluca',
 'B&B',
 "O'Dell",
 'Cabin',
 'Wastlgasse',
 'MM-505']
```

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the string in question slightly, and your method isn't going to work. Anyway thanks a lot for help!